# Returning a string in python and only getting an empty array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to return an array of a number's divisors. If the number is prime I want to return the string, '(integer) is prime'. Instead of returning this string my function returns an empty array.

Code:

```
def divisors(num):
    i = 2
    array = []
    while i < num:
        if num % i == 0:
            array.append(i)
        i += 1
    print(array)
    if len(array) > 0:
        return array
    else:
        prime = '%i is prime' %num
        return prime

divisors(3)
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: no it doesn't? https://repl.it/repls/BurlywoodJumboRectangle (presumably you are looking at the console output, where you _print_ the empty array, but you're not doing anything wth the result of the function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the empty array that you print when your function executes. Your function is correctly returning the string because 3 is prime, but you just haven't assigned the return value of the function to any variable. This should accomplish what you want.

```
def divisors(num):
    i = 2
    array = []
    while i < num:
        if num % i == 0:
            array.append(i)
        i += 1
    # print(array)
    if len(array) > 0:
        return array
    else:
        prime = '%i is prime' %num
        return prime

value = divisors(3)
print(value)
```

Output:

```
'3 is prime'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function does returns the string, the empty array you see is a result of the `print(array)` statement in the middle of your code, which I assume you added for debugging. Consider removing it.

Use `print(divisors(3))` to actually show the resulting string (otherwise it wouldn't show, as it does now).